# Issue regarding PHP file that echoes json string

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have troubles creating a json string to use in an android app for a few days now. I followed many tutorials, but it never was exactly  what i needed and I never understood this JSON stuff, although I tried to. So I wasn't able to modify it the way I wanted it.

First I tried this: http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-restful-webservice-tutorial-how-to-create-restful-webservice-in-java-part-2/

But this was with Logins, but I just want to read rows and display the data.

Maybe someone can help me and explain to me what I have to do to make it work.
The file should fetch a row from a table in my MySQL database that matches the city and country params and return it as json string.

**UPDATE:**
I now use the PDO_MYSQL extension and have new .php files.
But when I try to execute the file from the command line i get following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB_CONNECT_PDO::prepare() in get_data_pdo.php on line 15

My files:

db_connect_pdo.php:

class DB_CONNECT_PDO {

```
// constructor
function __construct() {
    // connecting to database
    $this->connect();
}

// destructor
function __destruct() {
    // closing db connection
    $this->close();
}

/**
 * Function to connect with database
 */
function connect() {
    try{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mydb;charset=utf8', 'myuser', 'mypass');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    }catch(PDOException $ex) {
        echo "An Error occured!";
        echo($ex->getMessage());
    }
    // returing connection cursor
    return $db;
}

/**
 * Function to close db connection
 */
function close() {
    // closing db connection
    mysqli_close();
}
```

}

get_data_pdo.php:

```
    $city = 'Berlin';
    $country = 'Germany';

    require_once('db_connect_pdo.php');

    try{
        $db = new DB_CONNECT_PDO();
        $con = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE city=? AND country=?");
        $stmt->execute(array($city, $country));
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(isset($rows)){
            echo json_encode($rows);
        }else{
            echo 'failure';
        }
    }catch(PDOException $ex) {
        echo "An Error occured!";
        echo($ex->getMessage());
    }
```

I followed this tutorial for the connection and sql query: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#External_links

Comment: "But when I tried to execute it it shows nothing."  Tell us how exactly you have tried to execute this? Did you send POST request ?

Comment: Where is $return_arr given a value? From what you've shown, I would expect $return_arr to be null, so it should echo a null - which looks like nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$con` variable is undefined in `getData.php`.

```
$sql = ...

$db = new DB_CONNECT();
$con = $db->connect();

$result = ...
```

**Important:** `mysql_connect` is deprecated since php 5.5 and removed in 7.0. I strongly advise against using it. You should look up PDO_MYSQL extension. 
More about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

You should also read about **sql injections**. Using unescaped user input in queries is a huge security flaw. PDO offers prepared statements and parameter binding to deal with sql injections.

**Edit:** As @tadman pointed out, there is also the issue of mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`. Connection is established using the `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` is used to execte the query and fetch the results.

**Edit 2:** Change `$stmt = $db->prepare(...);` to `$stmt = $con->prepare(...);`

`$db` is an instance of `DB_CONNECT_PDO` class, you can use it to prepare pdo statements, instead you must use `PDO` object created in `DB_CONNECT_PDO::connect`.

Best of luck!

Comment: There's also the issue of mixing `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` in this.

Comment: @tadman: Nice catch! You are absolutely right. I've edited the answer. Thanks! +1

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to use your suggested approach with MySQL PDO now with hard coded variable values, but get an Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB_CONNECT_PDO::prepare() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/get_data_pdo.php on line 15. The code I am trying to execute is: $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE city=? AND country=?"); When I got it right, the PDO driver should be enabled as of PHP 5.1.0. I am using 7.0.8. Should I edit my original question to update the new files with the new PDO code? Thanks in advance and sorry for being annoying.

Comment: You first need to connect to your db: `$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');`

Maybe it would be better if you update your question with new code, I can than update my answer accordingly. :)

Comment: I haven't been on StackOverflow very long and don't know if you get notified when I update my question, but I know that you can see it when I comment your answer, so I want to inform you that I updated my question :) Sorry if you already knew that

Comment: @boehmP: I've updated my answer, please let me know if the issue is solved now. :)

Comment: Thank you so much, it prints the json string now! :D But one last question: I get an error that mysqli_close function needs 1 argument, but has 0 in db_connect_pdo.php. When i try to use the $db variable as parameter, it shows the same error

Comment: @boehmP: You should remove `mysqli_close()` call completely. PDO connection will be closed automatically when object is destructed. Please, do not forget to mark correct answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I observed 3 things that might be given you problem

1. The file name is 'db_connect.php' which is expected to return your connection object, but in your code you are calling 'dbConnect.php'
2. $return_arr is not also define try to fix this
3. You might not send post request to getData.php and you are expecting response, try to hard-code city and country then run your getData.php. You should be fine

Comment: Thank you, I tried to replace the file name and use hard coded variable values. I also tried to echo the result and check variable, but nothing worked. So I tried the PDO approach that @Mladen Ilić suggested. But now I have another issue (500 internal server error). Please take a look at my comment under his answer

Comment: 500 internal server error is a generic error message, given when an unexpected condition was encountered and no more specific message is suitable. this is from your php file anyway, try and copy your query, run it  on your database and see if you have output, then you can know how to proceed